# How do I use OutputDebugString to print a message that's in a string variable?

Tags: string, delphi, variables

I recently had to do some changes in some Delphi code. Therefore, I have some basics questions:

1. Generally, how do I output to the console?
2. How do I output to the console with `fx` that is a string variable?

I started using `OutputDebugString`, but I couldn't get it working with a variable.

Comment: When you say "output to console" are you actually developing a console app or do you want debug output printed?

Comment: Its an application with a GUI. I just want to write out in the Event log for debugging variables like i'm used to in fx. Java.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421042/how-can-i-write-to-console-window-for-debugging

Comment: `{$IFDEF DEBUG}OutputDebugString(PChar(Format('Result = %d', [Result])));{$ENDIF}` (* save that as code template *)

Comment: OutputDebugString does not write to the "console" or "event log". Delphi calls it "event log" but it is not the Windows Event Log. It's a "debugger log". OutputDebugString sends string to a registered debugger. SysInternals calls its debug string utility Debug View correctly.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can write a wrapper function to take care of the variables passed to `OutputDebugString` as it expects a PChar.

Something like:

```
procedure DebugMsg(const Msg: String);
begin
    OutputDebugString(PChar(Msg))
end;
```

There is a useful reference for debugging techniques [here](http://www.blong.com/Conferences/BorCon2002/Debugging/3188.htm).

And if your Delphi is a bit rusty there's the ever useful [Delphi Basics](http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/) site. I use it a lot :)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the 2 answers you got about OutputDebugString() and WriteLn(), for debugging there is a better solution: CodeSite from Raize Software (see http://www.raize.com/DevTools/CodeSite/Default.asp ).

If you have Delphi XE, that should already come with an somewhat reduced functionality version of CodeSite.

Comment: CodeSite Express is available through the GetIt Package Manager

Answer (score 0):

If you have a console application, just use write() and writeln() global functions. If you have a  GUI application and want to create a separate console windows, things go tricky ([this article](http://www.halcyon.com/~ast/dload/guicon.htm) will guide you through the process, though it's in C++).

Comment: Can check "generate console application" in linker options.

Comment: It is also possible to redirect WriteLn so that you can e.g. use a form with a memo field in it to display anything passed to Write() or WriteLn()