# Delphi debug.print function?

Tags: delphi, printing, immediate-window

Does Delphi have a function similar to debug.print in VB, and if it does, how does one access the immediate window?
Thanks.

Comment: also : http://stackoverflow.com/q/4873356/327083, http://stackoverflow.com/q/397934/327083 ...

Comment: What makes you think debug output has anything to do with the immediate window (which in Delphi is known as the [Evaluate/Modify](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Overview_of_Debugging#Evaluate.2FModify) window)?

Comment: @Rob In VB Debug.Print does output to the immediate window

Comment: Bizarre dupe selection. Write to the console window? Debug.Print?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I picked the first of many - there are a lot of equally awkward questions like this that are essentially looking for the functionality of `OutputDebugString` to the Event Log... awkward in that they all misuse some terminology or other to describe as much without actually knowing what to call it.

Comment: @J... Marking it as a duplicate of a question that is completely different doesn't seem helpful to me. Pick a good duplicate

Comment: @DavidHeffernan the use case and feature need are basically identical.  The only difference is in the wording - one guy is asking for "console" output, this guy is asking for an "immediate window".  It seems clear that they are both looking for the standard thing that is *"that feature in this IDE whereby my application can output strings to a box such that I might monitor them whilst debugging"*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call the Windows API function `OutputDebugString`. Anything that is sent to that function appears in the Event Log window in the IDE (View | Debug Windows | Event Log).

Comment: Or in third-party debug viewers, like [SysInternals DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647), which are useful when debugging outside of the IDE.

Comment: @David, thanks! It really helps. I suppose it's only for string values? Can I print a value, eg enumerated type, to debug window as well?

Comment: Write a helper to convert other types to string and then call OutputDebugString.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau, DbgView is not really a debugger. It will read debug strings from the processes **not** being debugged.

Comment: Thank you all for the help.

Comment: @user539484: I never said DebugView was a debugger.  But it does intercept and display debug messages from `OutputDebugString()` (and a few others).